# How to install activiti "Create deployment artifacts " option inside eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, activiti

I want to be able to create a deployment artifacts for a project inside Eclipse Juno. I have installed activiti for eclipse, but still the  "Create deployment artifacts " option when I right click on a project is not there.

Answer (score 5):

View the project under "Package explorer" tab and perform right click.

Answer (score 0):

In package explorer Right Click on the Activiti Project then you will see Create Deployment Artifact

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to be under activiti perspective and then right click from the package explorer to see the Create deployment artifact as explained [here](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/219281-missing-create-deployment-artifacts). To open up the activiti perspective go to Window>Perspective>Open Perspective>Other... and then select Activiti